# Questions about Solana RPC response time

Tags: rpc, latency

[image]I'm playing with solana rpc method(official devnet rpc endpoint(https://api.devnet.solana.com
) like getBlock or getTransaction etc.. But I got response time toooo long, given that  it's not mainnet which has 3000 transactions in one block. getBlock took about **500~1500ms**, and getTransaction also took about **300ms**.
Is it usual?
I also tested alchemy private node but this also took long time to get response.

Comment: There's quite a few providers now https://solana.com/rpc, you can test with eg https://chainstack.com/protocols/solana/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getBlock` is a "larger" request than `getTransaction`, because it has much more data in its response. It has the data for all the transactions in the block, as opposed to fetching the data for a single transaction. It's expected for getBlock to take a little longer to respond than getTransaction.

As for overall latency, it is expected for rpc requests to take some time to respond. The speed also depends on the state of the network, and may be even slower if the RPC node that you're using is running behind schedule.